# Can I successfully access overseas networks after opening a VPN proxy, but why does gradle still fail to compile?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, vpn

Since I cannot access the overseas Internet locally, I opened a vpn, and then I can access overseas websites normally, but why Android studio still cannot download the corresponding gradle resources, causing the compilation to fail?
I have even opened a global proxy. Doesn't it take effect for the software, but only for web browsing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know what port your vpn is working on .

for example , if you downloaded [psiphone](https://psiphon.ca/en/download.html?psiphonca) , you can go to settings , then local proxy ports and you can add 12345 as port for example .

then you need to go to .gradle folder , if your using windows its usually located at USER/%USERNAME%/.gradle , and create a global gradle.properties and then add the following .

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=12345
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=12345
```

This will redirect all gradle connection throw your proxy , in the case psiphone for example.

Comment: thanks， it is effective.