# android studio: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to build a flutter app I get so many problems while building it and found a solutions for all of them but now I am stuck since the morning with this one:

```
> Task :firebase_auth:generateDebugRFile FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_auth:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find browser-1.0.0.aar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/browser/browser/1.0.0/browser-1.0.0.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 37s
```

my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:2.1.75'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my app build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inspireui.fluxstore"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'PUT_YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID_HERE',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'

    // For checking GMS availability.
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0"

    // Fix duplicate exoplayer
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.1'
}
googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }

//Fix android-r issue
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android") && project.property("android").compileSdkVersion.equals("android-R")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.propertis:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Solutions I tried:

- invalidate cache and restart
- flutter clean && flutter pub get
- gradlew clean && gradlew build
- delete the %USER%/.android and %USER%/.gradle and delete every thing related to android studio and reinstalled it
- use a VPN ( tried 3 )

but unfortunatly, nothing helped me

for further info: I am building [fluxstore app](https://codecanyon.net/item/fluxstore-woocommerce-flutter-ecommerce-full-app/24050041)

Answer (score 0):

I still think its a connection issue . is maven google available in your browser with no VPN ?

if no then here is a old [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778447/can-i-successfully-access-overseas-networks-after-opening-a-vpn-proxy-but-why-d/69778844?noredirect=1#comment123535435_69778844) of mine , on how to configure gradle to use you VPN properly . Because you need to tell gradle to send request over VPN using gradle.properties file .