# Set HTTPS proxy server for Gradle problem

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy

I want to set HTTPS proxy in Android Studio for Gradle. There is no standard options for set it via dialog box (HTTP or SOCK only), but according [this](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/build_environment.html) guide I set it via `gradle.properties` file in my project.

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost = 8.8.8.8 // just for example
systemProp.https.proxyPort = 8080
```

I found a free proxy server and checked it via web browser, but it is not work for Android Studio. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778844/11301941) of mine describing how to configure proxy over Gradle.

To make sure that the properties you have set is active, You can use the command line at the project directory (where `gradle.properties` is located) and type `gradle properties`, This should list all the active gradle properties at the current location.

You can also add to `gradle home` where it is usually located at `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/.gradle`, This way you will have a global setup, so you don't have to add the proxy to all `gradle.properties`

Comment: I run in AS in terminal window "gradlew properties". Two lines of proxy settings exist, but proxy not work. I need HTTPS proxy only, is this possible? So?

Comment: Are you sure of proxy and port ? Proxy accessible to the site with browser ?

Comment: Yes it is. But I not set HTTP parameters. I want to use HTTPS proxy only. Is this possible? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39415015/9057721

Comment: My proxy is free and not stable. May be delay more than 1 seconds.

Comment: Maybe try [psiphone](https://psiphon.ca/en/download.html?psiphonca) as suggested in my previous answer, Its also free but stable with the ability to configure port.

Comment: Upps! I restarted AS and this works! Last question. Is AS will cash downloaded dependences or will repeat it again and again? Thank you.