# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception: gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.2/gradle-7.2.2.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.2/gradle-7.2.2.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

File build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: I know you're new and therefor I should be gentle, but you didn't explain anything - what did you do, what did you expect, what did you try yourself? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for now a downvote

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's an access-related issue. You can try to check this link  with your browser https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.2/gradle-7.2.2.pom

you can see that there is an error, and it's not accessible for you.

And there are multiple ways to gain access.

Here is an old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778844/11301941) of mine explaining how to set up a valid connection.

You can also use some VPNs like [ProtonVPN](https://protonvpn.com/), which will have a system-wide effect.